# What are specific conditions under which it is considered okay to have Code behind logic in MVVM for a view?

Tags: c#, wpf, design-patterns, mvvm

I was reading up on MVVM and I am not still not fully certain around the following...

1. When can it be considered okay to have a code behind file in the View?
2. Can there still be decent MVVM apps without using Prism?
3. When is the right time to think about PRISM?
4. Which MVVM framework is user friendly with a smooth learning curve?

Answer (score 1):

If you can't take out the view portion of the code and replace it with another view (for example replace WPF with GTK# or WinForms) then the design is flawed.

Prism is geared towards WPF and isn't really all MVVM. With MVVM if you design the application around one presentation library you are in danger of creating anti-patterns. MVVM is very suitable for building cross-platform applications with C#, not just Windows applications. That includes GTK# for Windows/Linux/Mac, Cocoa Touch for iOS, AXML for Android etc. There is even Qt library somewhere but I don't think it is well supported anymore. You can even write native UI applications for Mac with C#.

Many people are using MvvmCross but I have avoided it for a few reasons. The bottom line is with good design you can live without heavy MVVM frameworks so don't rely too much on any framework without understanding how it works first.

http://www.geekchamp.com/articles/building-a-complete-cross--platform-mvvm-app-with-mvvmcross

Comment: I've worked with some designs that have really complex visual work occurring, but there is code-behind code in the view AND the view can be switched out for a different view - think 3D scenes, etc. I would say this is a place where MVVM still works, but code-behind makes sense more because the view logic itself is complicated. Do you think this might be a good example of a situation that still follows the principles you're setting forth but illustrates where code-behind is needed?

Answer (score 1):

To answer #4. I found prism to be heavy and cluttered.  The nicest (and easiest to grasp) in my oppinion is mvvm light.  The code templates are so nice that I don't start any wpf without it.

http://mvvmlight.codeplex.com